# Error when trying to get my simulation running

Tags: opengl

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. This is the error I am getting when I am trying to get my simulation running. Any idea how to solve this?

```
python3 -m motion_imitation.examples.test_env_gui --robot_type=A1 --motor_control_mode=Position --on_rack=True
pybullet build time: May 20 2022 19:43:01
/home/user/motion_imitation/motion_imitation/robots/a1.py:104: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arccos
  (2 * l_low * l_up))
/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gym/logger.py:30: UserWarning: WARN: Box bound precision lowered by casting to float32
  warnings.warn(colorize('%s: %s'%('WARN', msg % args), 'yellow'))
argv[0]=
startThreads creating 1 threads.
starting thread 0
started thread 0 
argc=3
argv[0] = --unused
argv[1] = 
argv[2] = --start_demo_name=Physics Server
ExampleBrowserThreadFunc started
X11 functions dynamically loaded using dlopen/dlsym OK!
X11 functions dynamically loaded using dlopen/dlsym OK!
Creating context
Created GL 3.3 context
Direct GLX rendering context obtained
Making context current
GL_VENDOR=Intel
GL_RENDERER=Mesa Intel(R) Graphics (ADL GT2)
GL_VERSION=4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.2.5
GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION=4.60
pthread_getconcurrency()=0
Version = 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.2.5
Vendor = Intel
Renderer = Mesa Intel(R) Graphics (ADL GT2)
b3Printf: Selected demo: Physics Server
startThreads creating 1 threads.
starting thread 0
started thread 0 
MotionThreadFunc thread started
  0%|                                                   | 0/800 [00:00<?, ?it/s]ven = Intel
Workaround for some crash in the Intel OpenGL driver on Linux/Ubuntu
ven = Intel
Workaround for some crash in the Intel OpenGL driver on Linux/Ubuntu
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████| 800/800 [00:36<00:00, 21.90it/s]
numActiveThreads = 0
stopping threads
Thread with taskId 0 exiting
destroy semaphore
semaphore destroyed
Thread TERMINATED
destroy main semaphore
main semaphore destroyed
finished
numActiveThreads = 0
btShutDownExampleBrowser stopping threads
Thread with taskId 0 exiting
Thread TERMINATED
destroy semaphore
semaphore destroyed
destroy main semaphore
main semaphore destroyed
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output you provided, there doesn't seem to be any clear error message. However, there are some warning messages and notes that appear in the output.

The warning message related to the "Box bound precision lowered by casting to float32" can usually be safely ignored, as it is a Gym library warning and not related to your simulation.

The other message related to the "invalid value encountered in arccos" is a runtime warning that might be related to some computation inside the a1.py script, which is part of your simulation's codebase. This warning may be related to a mathematical error, such as trying to calculate the inverse cosine of a value outside of the range of -1 to 1. You may want to check the code of the a1.py script for any potential issues.

Overall, I would recommend checking the documentation of the motion_imitation package and trying to understand what the test_env_gui script does, as well as the options you are passing to it. Additionally, you may want to check any installation requirements and ensure that all dependencies are properly installed. Finally, you may want to run your simulation with verbose logging enabled to get a better idea of what is happening during the simulation.